# Function optimization errors

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have the following *Mathematica* code (*Mathematica* version 9):

```
DH[x_] := (0.399582 Exp[-0.501606 (-3.57699 + Log[x])^2])/x   
F[n1_, n2_] := Integrate[DH[x], {x, n1, n2}];            
G[n_] := Integrate[DH[x], {x, 0, n - 1}];      
Cp[n1_, n2_] := Piecewise[{{F[n1, n2]*Log2[n1], n1 < n2},
                           {0, n1 >= n2}}];       
Et[n1_, n2_] := Piecewise[{{-F[n1, n2]*Log2[F[n1, n2]], n1 < n2 }, 
                           {0, n1 >= n2}}];  
H[n1_, n2_] := Piecewise[{{Cp[n1, n2] + Cp[n2, 233]- Et[n1, n2]-Et[n2, 233]-G[n1], n1 < n2},
                           {0, n1 >= n2}}];
```

I want to maximize value of `H[n1,n2]` and I use the `Maximize` function:

```
Maximize[{H[n1, n2],2<=n1<=231 && 3<=n2<=232 && n1 < n2}, {n1, n2}, Reals]
```

After I run the program, I obtained the solution: 
 {2.64505, {n1 -> 11.6199, n2 -> 232.}}

and many error messages. How obtain the maximum?

Comment: a general comment: try to avoid capitalized function names, especially if single letter (I see no conflicts in your case above (as you go for `DH`, `Cp`, `Et` in the critical cases), but you risk conflicting with built-in symbols, such as `D`, `C` etc.)

Comment: Your code contains a syntax error (bracket mismatch) in the `DH` definition. Please ensure your code runs properly as copied and pasted from the site. As `DH` is using reals, you might as well switch over to `NMaximize` directly (`Maximize` does it for you already).

Comment: I modified the message.Thanks for the observations.

Comment: Please remember to upvote good answers (and eventually accept your favorite one), see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest defining `F` and `G` using `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`, so that the integral is done just once:

```
F[n1_, n2_] = Integrate[DH[x], {x, n1, n2}, Assumptions -> {n1 > 0, n2 > 0}];
G[n_] = Integrate[DH[x], {x, 0, n - 1}];
```

For the maximization , you could try changing the `Method` option if the default is giving bad results. For example:

```
NMaximize[{H[n1, n2], 2 <= n1 <= 231 && 3 <= n2 <= 232 && n1 < n2}, {n1, n2}, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
(* {2.73157, {n1 -> 6.92863, n2 -> 18.3921}} *)
```

There is a [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html) on Numerical Nonlinear Global Optimization, with details about the various method options.